# how do i change registry permissions on specific keys and exclude others?

Tags: windows, permissions, registry

does anyone know how or if it's possible to change permissions on a numbers of registry keys in a subtree, but also also in the process, exclude several keys i don't want changing?

the trouble is they all have different names and if i create a batch file to change the ones i want to change, later on part of a key's name will change so i'll have to keep updating the batch, can i use wild cards to target the keys by the part of the name that stays the stay the same?

i.e. \somekey_0123456789 (the number bit changes but somekey doesn't)

hope this made some sense.